# How do I specify an empty alt attribute in React/JSX?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, accessibility, jsx

I'm trying to add an empty alt attribute to an img element in a react component like so

```
function SomeImageComponent(props) { 
  return <img src={props.imgSrc} alt="" />;
}
```

But when this is rendered to the DOM and I inspect it in dev tools I see a boolean type of attribute like this

```
<img src="/path/to/cat.gif" alt />
```

When I then test this with VoiceOver it ignores the valueless alt attribute and reads out the path to the image. So how can I get react to render an empty string for the attribute value?

Comment: Maybe with `alt={""}` ?

Comment: Unfortunately that does the same thing as the above

Comment: That's just how the dev tools display empty attributes. If you right-click the element and choose "Edit as HTML" you'll see that the empty string is there.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`alt` and `alt=""` are the same thing. From [the spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#attributes-0):

> Attributes can be specified in four different ways:
>
> **Empty attribute syntax**
>
> Just the attribute name. The value is implicitly the empty string.
>
> ...

It's true that you typically see this with boolean attributes, but it's not limited to them.

Example:

```js
var imgs = document.querySelectorAll("img");
var alt0 = imgs[0].getAttribute("alt");
var alt1 = imgs[1].getAttribute("alt");
console.log("0 (" + typeof alt0 + "): '" + alt0 + "'");
console.log("1 (" + typeof alt1 + "): '" + alt1 + "'");
```

```html
<img src="foo.png" alt>
<img src="bar.png" alt="">
```

It's worth noting that there are only a very few places where a blank `alt` is appropriate, but if you're supplying it at all, you're probably someone who's already aware of those places. :-)

Comment: So you're right - Turns out this isn't related to JSX. It's to do with how VoiceOver handles empty alt attributes. If you provide an empty string as the alt attribute it will still read out the image filename, whereas if you provide a single space character for the alt attribute it will skip over the image entirely which is what I was after.

Comment: Also FWIW I believe it's often more beneficial to provide an empty alt attribute. MIT's web-accessibility guidelines suggest: "ALT tags are often misused, mostly people overuse them. It’s better to leave the ALT tag blank (ALT=””) then to enter a text description that’s not useful or is redundant. For example an image with a caption below it does not need alt text that matches the caption, leave the alt text blank to avoid redundancy."

Comment: Note that the specs (https://www.w3.org/TR/html/semantics-embedded-content.html#the-img-element) make a difference between an alt that is not set ("no textual equivalent of the image") and an alt set to the empty string ("The image is either decorative or supplemental")

Comment: @Adam: Yes, of course; there's a big difference between an attribute that's missing and an attribute that's present with a blank value.

Answer (score 2):

Can we also add alt tags?
By doing this, we can overcome Google & tools errors notifications

```
<img src="foo.png" alt="foo">
<img src="bar.png" alt="bar">
```